# Would this grain bill make an Amber Ale?

Tags: all-grain, recipe-formulation, biab

I am planning a small experimental 1 gallon BIAB batch of something like an Amber Ale.  According to one article I've found:

**Description of Typical Grain Bill**

> Amber Ale is traditionally made with American two row pale malt as the
>   base, making up 60-85% of the grain bill. Medium to dark crystal malts
>   are used to provide color and caramel flavor, typically making up
>   10-20% of the grain bill.

**My Proposed Grain Bill**

- 2 lbs. Briess Organic 2-Row
- 0.5 lb.  Briess Caramel 60L
- 0.5 lb.  Crisp Amber Malt

If I were to follow the amounts above, which would put my base malt at 66% and medium/dark malts at 33% (higher than normal for this style), what would I get?

Would it simply be a darker than normal Amber Ale or would it cross into another style?

Comment: What's your desired original gravity?  That would play an important role, too — determining how much by way of fermentables you should be working with.

Comment: Good point. I've plugged it in to Beer Smith and that tells me I should get an OG of around 1.057 which seems to be on the high, but acceptable end for this style. Thanks for your input. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

I figure approximately 20-22 SRM.  You might be pushing the color a bit towards the darker end, but it will work I think.  Maybe go to 7oz each of the C60 and the Amber.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I'll update with the actual SRM when it's finished. Cheers!

Comment: It turned out alright, a bit more roasted flavor than I would have liked, but not bad IMO. The SRM came in around 28/29.